# (in R) Add metadata from a vector to a set of columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, metadata, attr

I would like to use values from a character vector that I created as label attributes for a set of variables in a dataframe.

I thought this simple solution should work, yet it does not:

```
x <- rep("text", time=19) %>% 
  paste(1:19, sep = " ")  #character vector with names of label attributes I want

attr(mydataframe[var_names], "label") <- x #var_names and x have the same length
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want the column names of your data.frame to be `x`? If so, try `colnames(mydataframe) <- x`

Comment: Thanks for your welcome and such a fast reply! I would like to automatically assign label atributes for a subset of variables within a dataframe. The solution by G. Grothendieck works, I rewrote it to use with no hmisc. If smdy knows another way, I would like to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmisc supports column labels. Using the built in data frame `anscombe` having 8 columns:

```
library(Hmisc)

x <- paste("label", i)

for(i in seq_along(anscombe)) label(anscombe[[i]]) <- x[i]
Label(anscombe)
```

giving:

```
label(x1)       <- 'label 1'
label(x2)       <- 'label 2'
label(x3)       <- 'label 3'
label(x4)       <- 'label 4'
label(y1)       <- 'label 5'
label(y2)       <- 'label 6'
label(y3)       <- 'label 7'
label(y4)       <- 'label 8'
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your idea to work with attributes (no hmisc required)            `for (i in seq_along(mydata)) {
 attr(mydata[[i]], "label") <- x[[i]] #x contains labels I need
}`

Comment: Then you are missing out on the "labelled" class methods that Hmisc provides.